# is it possible to open a .bak file in sql without connecting to a database?

Tags: sql, database, restore, database-backups

i have a .bak file and i want to check its data before importing it to host ! i tried to open it with MS SQL server management studio to see data inside the backup file. i googled a lot but i couldnt understand how to open this file ! i saw every solution to import a .bak file in a existed database ! i have no database on my local computer. how can i check my backup file data ? anyone can help ?

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some 3rd party tools. Try searching google for "open bak file without sql server".

Also there is free SQL express, so you can install server on your local computer and attach database. Default installation should do the trick.

You can even open it in notepad, but it's not very practical..

Comment: But note that SQL Server Express is [limited to 10GB database size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15#Cross-BoxScaleLimits) - which may or may not be relevant to the OP.

Comment: thanks a lot ! i downloaded a 3rd party app, named "SysTools SQL Backup Recovery" and i could see my data.